# Communication between CUDA threads/thread blocks

Tags: cuda, synchronization, gpu

I am trying to "map" a few tasks to CUDA GPU. There are n tasks to process. (See the pseudo-code)

```
malloc an boolean array flag[n] and initialize it as false.
for each work-group in parallel do
    while there are still unfinished tasks do
        Do something;
        for a few j_1, j_2, .. j_m (j_i<k) do
            Wait until task j_i is finished; [ while(flag[j_i]) ;  ]
            Do Something;
        end for
        Do something;
        Mark task k finished;  [  flag[k] = true;  ]
    end while
end for
```

For some reason, I will have to use threads in different thread block.

The question is how to implement the **Wait until task j_i is finished;** and **Mark task k finished;** in CUDA. My implementation is to use an boolean array as the flag. Then set flag once a task is done, and read the flag to check if a task is done.

But it only works on small case, one large case, the GPU get crashed with unknown reason. Is there any better way to implement the **Wait** and **Mark** in CUDA.

That's basically a problem of inter-thread communication on CUDA.

Comment: You will have to use atomic operations for this.. That costs a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont need to implement in CUDA. Every thing can be implemented on CPU. You are waiting for a task to complete, then doing another task randomly. If you want to implement in CUDA, you dont need to wait for all the flags to be true. You know initially that all the flags are false. So just implement `Do something` in parallel for all the thread and change the flag to true.

If you want to implement in CUDA, take `int flag` and keep on adding 1 it after finishing `Do something` so that you can know the change in flag before and after doing `Do something`.

If i got your question wrong, please comment. I'll try to improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronising within a threadblock is straightforward using `__syncthreads()`. However synchronising between threadblocks is more tricky - the programming model method is to break into two kernels.

If you think about it, it makes sense. The execution model (for both CUDA and OpenCL) is for a whole bunch of blocks executing on processing units, but says nothing about when. This means that some blocks will be executing but others will not (they'll be waiting). So if you have a `__syncblocks()` then you would risk deadlock, since those already executing will stop, but those not executing will never reach the barrier.

You can share information between blocks (using global memory and atomics, for example), but not global synchronisation.

Depending on what you're trying to do, there is frequently another way of solving or breaking down the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't make the question clear. What I am trying to do is to **ask one thread to wait for the data from the other thread**. For example, thread #2 needs the results in thread #1. That means part of thread #2 has to be launched after thread #1 is finished.  <br/>  So I wanna know is there any function like "sem_post" and "sem_wait" that passes massage in between 2 threads? or I will have to write (thread #1) and read (thread #2) the global memory, even though it is very inefficient? @Mark Ebersole

Comment: Within a block you can use shared memory for communication between threads (with __syncthreads()), between threads in different blocks, see my answer: you can't synchronise blocks since that could cause deadlock.

Comment: I see. Still in the example, if thread #2 needs the data from is thread #1. (Thread #2 checking the "flag" global memory, and thread #1 write the "flag" global memory when it is done). Then the thread #2 will always check the memory and occupy the bus, thus thread #1 can't successfully write the "flag" to the memory.  If they are in the same thread block, we can use __syncthreads() to ensure the writing is complete, then starts the rest part of thread #2?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I rephrase the problem description, now it looks much clear. Can you help take a look at the question again.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not easily done since thread blocks can be scheduled in any order, and there is no easy way to synchronize or communicate between them.  From the CUDA Programming Guide:

> For the parallel workloads, at points in the algorithm where parallelism is broken because some threads need to synchronize in order to share data with each other, there are two cases: Either these threads belong to the same block, in which case they should use __syncthreads() and share data through shared memory within the same kernel invocation, or they belong to different blocks, in which case they must share data through global memory using two separate kernel invocations, one for writing to and one for reading from global memory. The second case is much less optimal since it adds the overhead of extra kernel invocations and global memory traffic. Its occurrence should therefore be minimized by mapping the algorithm to the CUDA programming model in such a way that the computations that require inter-thread communication are performed within a single thread block as much as possible.

So if you can't fit all the communication you need within a thread block, you would need to have multiple kernel calls in order to accomplish what you want.

I don't believe there is any difference with OpenCL, but I also don't work in OpenCL.

Comment: And @Tom beats me by 4 minutes... :)

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't make the question clear. What I am trying to do is to let one thread to wait for the data from the other thread. For example, thread #2 needs the results in thread #1. That means part of thread #2 has to be launched after thread #1 is finished. <br/> So I wanna know is there any function like "sem_post" and "sem_wait" that passes massage in between 2 threads? or I will have to write (thread #1) and read (thread #2) the global memory, even though it is very inefficient?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I rephrase the problem description, now it looks much clear. Can you help take a look at the question again.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problems is best solved by a slightly different approach:

Don't assign fixed tasks to your threads, forcing your threads to wait until their task becomes available (which isn't possible in CUDA since threads can't block).

Instead, keep a list of available tasks (using atomic operations) and have each thread grab a task from that list.

This is still tricky to implement and get the corner cases right, but at least it's possible.

Comment: In this way, I needs to keep a list of available tasks, but it is very complicated in this application. Is it possible to implement the "Wait" and "Mark" in CUDA?

Comment: No, there is no way for a thread to wait for anything outside of it's own block.

Comment: You can simplify the bookkeeping for the list of tasks quite a bit by keeping two separate lists of available tasks - one where tasks are taken from to be processed, and another where tasks are added when they get ready. Once all tasks from the first list are processed, you swap the lists and start a new kernel. This incurs a slight performance penalty, but makes the list management really simple.